# How to get hostname and IP address of an arbitrary jenkins node in a pipeline job

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a jenkins pipeline job that is parametrized. The only parameter is of type Node (named myNode), where I have always available all the nodes of the jenkins server.

[image]

In my groovy pipeline, I want to set two variables:

```
 - hostname of the node (myNode)
 - IP address of the node (myNode)
```

I tried many options but I can't get both hostname and IP address and I also get different results depending if the slave is windows or linux.
In my mind, because jenkins know the nodes, it would be something simple but it seems is not.

What I've tried:

```
def find_ip(node_name){
    for (slave in Jenkins.instance.slaves) {
        host = slave.computer.hostName
        addr = InetAddress.getAllByName(host)
        if (! slave.name.trim().equals(node_name.trim())) { continue }
        String rawIpAddress = addr[0]
        ipAddress = rawIpAddress.substring(rawIpAddress.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)
        print "ipAddress: " + ipAddress
        
        return host
    }
}

node('master') {
    stage('stage1') {
        println "hostname: " + find_ip(env.myNode)
    }
}
```

If the slave is windows, I get the hostname and ipaddress correctly. If it's linux, I get the IP address on both fields.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So, what have you tried and why it's not working?

Comment: I added what I tried.

Comment: I changed the original code. I can get both values that I want but only for Windows slaves. For linux I can't get the hostname.

Comment: EDIT: it seems that for other linux machines, I can get the hostname correctly. Only for one of them is not possible and it returns the ipaddress instead. Tha machine, in fact has 3 ip addresses, I don't know if that's the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def find_ip(node_name){
    def node = Jenkins.instance.slaves.find{it.name.trim()==node_name.trim()}
    if(node) {
        def addr = InetAddress.getByName(node.computer.hostName)
        def ip = addr.getHostAddress()
        def host = addr.getHostName()
        println "host=${host} ip=${ip}"
        return host
    }
}
```

Comment: I get this error: hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: [Ljava.net.InetAddress;.getHostAddress() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:154)

Comment: EDIT: addr is a list so it must be changed to addr[0]. It works fine this way

Comment: Only issue I have now is that one of the machines is returning the IP instead of hostname

Comment: it means name could not be resolved by ip. something with network config